# Put XSLT filename into Output

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to put the name of the XLST file doing the transformation into my final output file. Is there a way to do this within XSLT?

My searches keep coming up with the XML filename.

For example, if this was Perl, I'd be using the $0 variable. The closest I can figure is passing it in as a parameter which seems rather redundant.

---

So I found the answer to getting the XSLT filename + path, but now I'm a bit confused (and want others to find this answer easier). So the correct answer will have the following three filenames and if there is a way to get the filename without the full path:

- XSLT filename:
- XML Input filename:
- XML Output filename:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 the `static-base-uri()` function will get you close. But the notion that that there is a single unique filename associated with the stylesheet is over-simplistic: it might be assembled from a large collection of files using include/import or XML entities, or it might be built in memory, with no files involved.

Comment: Doesn't base-uri(document('')) give the filename of the current stylesheet? I didn't know you could build a stylesheet in memory, and that would certainly not fit in this scenario. Does this mean there is no function for input/output filenames even in basic situations?

Comment: There should be a _very_ special hat for editing Michael Kay's answer to an XSLT question.

Comment: `document('')` is equivalent to `document(static-base-uri())`, so it will take the URI, retrieve the document, and build a tree, and applying base-uri() to the result will then tell you where it came from. So it's 100% equivalent and probably 100 times slower. And it suffers exactly the same problems: if there's no single file location associated with the stylesheet, then there's not necessarily a clear answer. But in simple cases where you're not doing anything clever, static-base-uri() will give you the location of the stylesheet module in which the function call appears.

Comment: (In recent Saxon releases where compiled stylesheets can be developed on one machine and executed on another, static-base-uri() should give you the location of the compiled stylesheet, not the location of the original source code.)